# What is your favorite new feature of SE that's been rolled out in the past few months?

Tags: discussion

I was gone from SO for a while the past few months and now that I'm getting back into it, it seems like tons of features have popped up(as well as I assume less-obvious bug fixes).

Anyway, I thought I'd stroke all the developers' ego and make a list of everyone's favorite features. Possibly they can use this list in the future to help assess what features aren't being used or are not favored by the community(and thus can be removed).

Answer (score 8):

By far my favorite and most used new feature has been the super-duper-mega drop down box for StackExchange. No longer do I have to try to visit every SE just to find if I have notifications. I just go to one and instantly know! Also, if I'm bored, I can check out all the latest questions from a combination of all the SE sites. All from one click. It's awesome.

Comment: yes, this change is the most transformative IMO

Comment: Yup +1 for the global inbox :)

Comment: This is definitely what's gotten me to branch out a little bit more into other sites.

Answer (score 3):

The **peer-reviewed edits** feature has the potential to increase the quality of the text on the sites, dramatically. Low-rep users can now make edits pending approval of mods or higher-rep users.

Comment: This is considerably more noticable on newer SE sites where less >2K rep users exist. As a user on those sites, I love the feature

Answer (score 1):

My best new feature has been the **highlighting on the Favorite tagged questions** in the unanswered list. It is such small features which are very user-friendly makes SO such a nice site to attract more people.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how long the few months are, and whether you count it as being "on" SO/SE, there's chat of course...

Comment: oddly, I haven't used chat that much. Not sure why, it just seems kinda pointless to me. Before it existed I loved the idea though

Comment: @Earlz, Depends a lot on your timezone. I tend to hang out in the [meta Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general). [Interesting things](http://se.awio.com/election.html) are born there sometimes...

Comment: I'm in Central/US. but I'm never online til about 6pm. Everytime I look in chat it's mostly dead(last message sent an hour ago and such).